# How to interpolate hue with svg gradient?

Tags: svg, colors, linear-gradients

I'd like an svg shape with a gradient that runs from `hsl(0, 100%, 50%)` to `hsl(360, 100%, 50%)`, where the hue runs smoothly from 0 -> 360, to create something like:

[image: Smooth gradient through hue]

When I make a gradient with these stop colours:

```
<linearGradient id="Gradient1">
  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="hsl(0, 100%, 50%)"/>
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="hsl(360, 100%, 50%)"/>
</linearGradient>
```

…it results in a fully red gradient

I've managed to [hack around](https://jsfiddle.net/hn0w29g4/) it slightly by adding more stops:

```
<linearGradient id="Gradient2">
  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="hsl(0, 100%, 50%)"/>
  <stop offset="1%" stop-color="hsl(3, 100%, 50%)"/>
  <stop offset="2%" stop-color="hsl(7, 100%, 50%)"/>
  <!-- Lots more -->
  <stop offset="98%" stop-color="hsl(352, 100%, 50%)"/>
  <stop offset="99%" stop-color="hsl(356, 100%, 50%)"/>
</linearGradient>
```

Though is seems pretty ugly.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Color interpolation in SVG is done using the sRGB color space (although you should be able to specify linearRGB but I don't think it's well supported), so you can't do what you want - those HSL colors are converted to sRGB before they're interpolated.

(And technically HSL colors aren't supported in SVG 1.1 - so while this works in Chrome, don't be surprised if it doesn't work everywhere)

Comment: Firefox supports linearRGB in nightlies now, slated for release in version 123.

Answer (score 5):

### Gradient stops every 60 degrees!

Because of how [hsl and rgb interact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#/media/File:HSV-RGB-comparison.svg), you will achieve the best results by having gradient stops every 60 degrees on the hue. Adding more stops or in
other places, makes the result worse.

Using hex, html color names,rgb, or hsl to define the gradient should all create the same results in a web browser because all of it converts to rgb in the end. I'm not sure about hsl svg compatibility outside web browsers, to be on the safe side I would stick to rgb or hex in most cases.

```html
<svg width=100%>
  <rect width=100%           height="1em" fill="url(#hslGradient)"/>
  <rect width=100% y="1.5em" height="1em" fill="url(#nameGradient)"/>
  <rect width=100% y="3em"   height="1em" fill="url(#rgbGradient)"/>
  <rect width=100% y="4.5em" height="1em" fill="url(#hexGradient)"/>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="hslGradient">
      <stop offset=0%   stop-color="hsl(  0, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset=16%  stop-color="hsl( 60, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset=33%  stop-color="hsl(120, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset=50%  stop-color="hsl(180, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset=66%  stop-color="hsl(240, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset=83%  stop-color="hsl(300, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset=100% stop-color="hsl(360, 100%, 50%)" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="nameGradient">
      <stop offset=0%   stop-color="red"    />
      <stop offset=16%  stop-color="yellow" />
      <stop offset=33%  stop-color="lime"   />
      <stop offset=50%  stop-color="cyan"   />
      <stop offset=66%  stop-color="blue"   />
      <stop offset=83%  stop-color="magenta"/>
      <stop offset=100% stop-color="red"    />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id=rgbGradient>
      <stop offset=0%   stop-color="rgb(255,  0,  0)"/>
      <stop offset=16%  stop-color="rgb(255,255,  0)"/>
      <stop offset=33%  stop-color="rgb(  0,255,  0)"/>
      <stop offset=50%  stop-color="rgb(  0,255,255)"/>
      <stop offset=66%  stop-color="rgb(  0,  0,255)"/>
      <stop offset=83%  stop-color="rgb(255,  0,255)"/>
      <stop offset=100% stop-color="rgb(255,  0,  0)"/>
    </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id=hexGradient>
      <stop offset=0%   stop-color="#f00"/>
      <stop offset=16%  stop-color="#ff0"/>
      <stop offset=33%  stop-color="#0f0"/>
      <stop offset=50%  stop-color="#0ff"/>
      <stop offset=66%  stop-color="#00f"/>
      <stop offset=83%  stop-color="#f0f"/>
      <stop offset=100% stop-color="#f00"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

If we are talking about the web, I would personaly just use a css gradient.

```css
html {
  background: linear-gradient(to right,
    #f00,
    #ff0,
    #0f0,
    #0ff,
    #00f,
    #f0f,
    #f00)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Full hsl gradient 0 - 360

By setting the stops colors at 10% i get a shape close to the image:
[image]

```html
<svg height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 20">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Gradient2">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="hsl(0, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="hsl(36, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="hsl(72, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset="30%" stop-color="hsl(108, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset="40%" stop-color="hsl(144, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="hsl(180, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset="60%" stop-color="hsl(252, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="hsl(236, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset="80%" stop-color="hsl(288, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="hsl(324, 100%, 50%)" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="hsl(360, 100%, 50%)" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <line stroke-width="16" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="url(#Gradient2)" x1="10" y1="10" y2="10.1" x2="90" />
</svg>
```

If you want to see how stops colors at 1% are here is a fiddle created by [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry):
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hn0w29g4/1/)

Included with comparison to the 10% stops.

If you think that there are to many stop colors then you could use javascript to add each stop element. But i think that just adding them manually is a better aproach in general.

Comment: yup, it's pretty close with 10 stops (here's a comparison of 2, 10 & 100 - https://jsfiddle.net/8q0jnu54/2/ - you lose a bit of brightness of the yellow, and it appears to move in slightly).  I was wondering if there was another way to natively do this interpolation rather than relying on generating stops elsewhere?